# How to show multiple results count for each day in one month

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm not familiar with query langguange especially mysql. So I have test project that have 2 table that contain some dummy data. Here is the table:

**Outlet table**

[image: Outlet table]

**Order table**

[image: Order table]

I want want to count status devide it to two different columns, status and status_1. Status 1 criteria is order.status = 1 and for status_1 = 2. The picture below is expected result

**Expected result**

[image]

I've only tried this coz I dont know how to get the status_1 value

as you can see here:

[image: query]

there's no status_1

and here's the result:

Can someone help me to solve this? Or give any clue? Still don't get it with the logic

Comment: I think your expected output is wrong. Because for date '2021-08-01' status 2 is existed. so result will status_1 = 0 and status_1 = 1

Comment: Thanks rahul. I forgot to change that to 1. Lets say the value is 1 and how can I get status_2 value?

Comment: Sorry I'm new here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry about that. I'm still noob and new here so I don't know how to ask properly. Anyway this problem is solved rn. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use case statement in count() function for retrieving desired result.

```
-- MySQL
SELECT o.name, od.tdate
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN od.status = 1 THEN 1 END) status_1
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN od.status = 2 THEN 1 END) status_2
FROM outlet_tbl o
INNER JOIN order_tbl od
        ON o.id = od.outlet_id
GROUP BY o.name, od.tdate
```

Please check from https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d7c74940fccf9149132dfc4e90072d06

Comment: @RizkyPrasetya please check this result.

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for bothering you. I'll try and implement it on my project asap

Comment: Welcome @RizkyPrasetya. If this answer help you then please mark as accepted (Green tick mark) and also a upvote so that other can pick this answer without any doubt if necessary.